# PDO, MySQL - Using a single CASE to UPDATE/Increment Values from Array Efficiently

Tags: mysql, performance, pdo, case

Authors are allowed to submit articles as part of a community and save them to a mysql database, with a PDO query. Let us expand this example with 7 articles:

```
article_id   author_id   article_title   article_clean   article_kind   good_read
    1            2       War and Peace   war-and-peace     free            y
    2            3       Art of War      art-of-war        free            y
    3            2       Peace and Love  peace-and-love    paid            n
    4            4       Peaceful Living peaceful-living   paid            n
    5            2       Peace Treaties  peace-treaties    free            n
    6            2       Peace is Love   peace-is-love     free            n
    7            4       Peace Countries peace-countries   free            n
```

I already have the output from the article ids:

```
while($row = $articles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){           
    $article_id_array[] = $row["article_id"];
    $author_id_array[] = $row["author_id"];
    $article_clean_array[] = $row["article_clean"];
    $article_kind_array[] = $row["article_kind"];
}
```

I'm trying to run a single mysql command, perhaps using CASE, that will only affect the articles like this:
1. All (free or paid) articles in the article_id_array will get a 'y'
Here's where the CASE comes in:
2. Only (free) articles of a single author_id, will get an article_title 'Good Read' and an article_clean     'good-read'
3. Only (free) articles, if for a single author_id, an article_title 'Good Read' and an article_clean 'good-read'     already exist, whether from the mysql query, or already exists in the articles table for that author_id, then a     value of 1 would be appended as such:
     article_title 'Good Read 1' and an article_clean 'good-read-1'

So in the above example, after the query, the articles table would look like this:

```
article_id   author_id   article_title   article_clean   article_kind   good_read
    1            2       Good Read       good-read         free            y
    2            3       Good Read       good-read         free            y
    3            2       Peace and Love  peace-and-love    paid            y
    4            4       Peaceful Living peaceful-living   paid            y
    5            2       Good Read 1     good-read-1       free            y
    6            2       Good Read 2     good-read-2       free            y
    7            4       Good Read       good-read         free            y
```

Any idea what a single PDO query to accomplish this task would be?
**EDIT:**
I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this, as this table may grow really fast (hundreds of thousands of articles), so the query I'm after can't cripple the database. For reference, this won't be for every single article in the db, just 20-100 article ids given to the script to execute the query against at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is MySQL without analytical functions like ROW_NUMBER you have to simulate it using OUTER JOIN - which is btw. not a good option in terms of performance. If I understand correctly the task, you can achieve this by running that query:

```
 SELECT article_id,
       author_id,
       CASE
         WHEN article_kind = 'free' THEN
           CASE
             WHEN num = 1 THEN 'Good Read'
             ELSE Concat('Good Read ', Cast((num - 1) AS CHAR))
           end
         WHEN article_kind = 'paid' THEN article_title
       end AS article_title,
       CASE
         WHEN article_kind = 'free' THEN
           CASE
             WHEN num = 1 THEN 'good-read'
             ELSE Concat('good-read-', Cast((num - 1) AS CHAR))
           end
         WHEN article_kind = 'paid' THEN article_title
       end AS article_clean,
       article_kind,
       'y' AS good_read
FROM   (SELECT a.article_id,
               a.author_id,
               a.article_title,
               a.article_clean,
               a.article_kind,
               a.good_read,
               Count(*) AS num
        FROM   articles AS a
               LEFT OUTER JOIN articles AS b
                            ON a.author_id = b.author_id
                               AND a.article_id >= b.article_id
                               AND b.article_kind = 'free'
        GROUP  BY article_id,
                  author_id,
                  article_title,
                  article_clean,
                  article_kind,
                  good_read) AS tab;
```

Comment: This works, except "Good Read 1 good-read-1" and "Good Read 2     good-read-2" never show up after the query is run, only "Good Read good-read" shows up, not sure why. What do you think is the most efficient way to do this, in terms of the speed of the query? This may be slow on a huge table?

Comment: Hmm.. This also doesn't SET/UPDATE the values in the table, it just selects.

Comment: Well, you can now do sth like this: `UPDATE update_table a, reference_table b SET a.col1 = b.col2 WHERE a.id = b.id`. As for why it was not working correctly, I made a mistake and switched `author_id` with `article_id` - already corrected, rerun the query.

Comment: With this query, article_id 7, displays "Good Read 1 good-read-1" instead of "Good Read good-read", since the author_id has not been repeated for "free" Also, can you demonstrate what the actual query would look like to set/update the actual table without the select? As for efficiency, can you read my edit to the question and tell me if this would be efficient?

Comment: Can you place that sample on sqlfiddle, I'd be able then to examine the solution... As for performance, if it's only 20 - 100 articles it would be better to create some temporary table, move the articles there, make an update, and put back into main table - providing that you have proper indexes.

Comment: [sqlfiddle link.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8da8b/1) Can you also share how to do the performance code? I have an index on article_id, and will be using IN($articleids) for the changes of the query to be applied.

Comment: I was rather thinking about creating a temporarty table with the above query results, like `CREATE TABLE temp_articles AS SELECT ...` adding WHERE clause with article IDs, like ` ... WHERE article_id IN (1, 4, 6), then update the old table, like `UPDATE articles a, temp_articles b SET a.article_title=b.article_title, a.article_clean=b.article_clean, a.good_read=b.good_read WHERE a.article._id=b.article_id` and remove the temporary table at the end.

Comment: By the way, the query is corrected so it returns proper results.

Comment: Hmmm.. with 4 more articles added, I can't get the query to work as intended. Here is the [sqlfiddle link.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2401a/9) The last row should be Good Read 3 (based on the IN article_ids), instead of the returned Good Read 5. The query is factoring in article_ids 8 & 9, even though they were not included in the IN clause. Any clue on how to fix this minor issue? Thank you for your help so far:)

Comment: This is not how I expected this to work, but to have it like that add the condition for the second table, like that: `... a.article_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11) and b.article_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11) ...`. No problem. ;-)

Comment: Hmmm.. For any single user, they cannot have a duplicate article_title or article_clean. I added one more row, row 12, which should be picked up for the update, and changed row 11 title/clean to "Good Read" and "good-read" The issue is that, since "Good Read" and "good-read" already exist in the table for user 2 as "free" (article_id 11), the sql query doesn't factor it in, and article_id 1, in the temp table will now have the same title/clean as article_id 11. Is there a way to fix the duplicate issue so when the update happens, there are no 2 duplicates for the same user under "free"?

Comment: This is getting pretty complicated as for sucha query. :-) Finding a solution is probably possible, but for sure too complicated. I would suggest for you to change the sstructure a bit... for example add new column `SEQ` where you will store the numbers that you've been appending so far. Than it would be easier to extract maximum numbers, increment them and continue for the next update. Anyway, it looks like another problem now, and I think the oryginal question was already answered, don't you think so? :-)